# Two elements print in one foreach loop than next loop start

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

when I use foreach loop for this

```
foreach($foo as $val):  
    print '<li>'.$val.'</li>';  
endforeach
```

Out put is ,

```
<li> 1 </li>  
<li> 2 </li>  
<li> 3 </li>  
<li> 4 </li>  
<li> 5 </li>
```

But I want out put something like that

```
<li> 1, 2 </li>  
<li> 3, 4 </li>  
<li> 5, 6 </li>  
<li> 7, 8 </li>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: There is no `endforeach`. I am assuming that is pseudo-code?

Comment: it's just an example.. forget the syntax error. but i need the output as i given above. Thanks

Comment: There certainly is endforeach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600419/endforeach-in-loops , http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php . The syntax is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you require:

```
foreach($foo as $key=>$val) {
    if ($val&1) {
        echo '<li>' . $val;
        if($key == (count($foo)-1)){
            echo '</li>';
        }
    } else {
        echo ',' . $val . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though this code works, it still needs to be improved. It will work correctly only on arrays with an even number of elements. If the count is odd, it will result in this `<li>9` - the last `<li>`-tag never gets closed.

Comment: @insertusernamehere You're right, and I have updated the answer, but it is still somewhat hackish. I think james.haggerty's solution is the best.

Answer (score 4):

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
foreach (array_chunk($foo, 2) as $chunk) {
    echo "<li>" . implode(', ', $chunk) . "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For php you can do:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($foo);$i+=2) {
    echo "<li>{$foo[$i]}, {$foo[$i+1]}</li>";
}
```

Comment: Although this code works fine, it will throw a `Notice: Undefined offset` as you do not check whether `$foo[$i+1]` exists. Also the last line will look like `<li>9,</li>` and not `<li>9</li>` which would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

$i=1;
$firstElement = "";

foreach($foo as $val):  

    if($i%2==0)
    {
        print '<li>'.$firstElement.','.$val.'</li>';  
    }
    else
    {
        $firstElement = $val;
    }   

    $i++;

endforeach
```

Comment: Please improve the code. It doesn't print out anything, as you forgot to increase `$i`. There is also an error in the line starting with `print`: You concat strings using `.` (a dot), so a `,` (a comma) won't work here.

Comment: Foreach will loop through your array, but it won't increase `$i`.

Comment: -1 removed. This one works, but still only on arrays with an even count.