# Test For Empty Text Inputs In A Table Row

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a bootstrap modal that I populate with data from the db if there are rows of data to display. (First Name, Last Name, Class Rank).

I have the ability to add and remove rows prior to saving the data and 
I want to be able to gather rows of data from the table and create a data object that I can pass to the back end at save.  The code I have so far is as follows:

HTML

```
<?php foreach ($athletes as $i => $row) { ?>
        <?php $i == 0 ? $rownum = 1 : $rownum = $i+1; ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
          <td><?php echo $rownum; ?><input type="hidden" name="data[id]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="data[first_name]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="data[last_name]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="data[classrank]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['class']; ?>" ></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="remScnt" class="btn btn-default">Remove Row</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
```

jQuery Save Function

```
$("button#saveaths").click(function() {
  var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
  var ath_data = [];
  $("tr").each(function() {

      if (data[first_name] != '') {
        ath_data.push(this.data[first_name]);
        ath_data.push(this.data[last_name]);
        ath_data.push(this.data[classrank]);
        ath_data.push(user_id);
      }
  });
});
```

I'm getting an error on the if statement.

At this stage, I'm only trying to build the data object that I can pass to a codeigniter controller to be inserted into my db.

Additionally, if there's a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your error is on the jQuery if statement, then the PHP that is used to generate is irrelevant. All that matters is what the HTML that was generated from the PHP looked like. Also, one suggestion is that you use things like endforeach when you are doing inline PHP like in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600419/endforeach-in-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the correct syntax to get the values of the fields.

Try this

```
$("button#saveaths").on("click",function() {
  var userID = $("#user_id").val();
  var ath_data = [];
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var firstName = $(this).find("[name=data[first_name]]").val();
    if (firstName != '') {
      var lastName = $(this).find("[name=data[last_name]]").val(),
          classRank = $(this).find("[name=data[classrank]]").val();
      ath_data.push({firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,classRank:classRank,userID:userID});
    }
  });
  if (ath_data.length>0) {
    $.ajax({ 
      type="POST",
      url:"someServerProcess.php",
      data: JSON.stringify(ath_data),
      contentType: "application/json"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:  
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: name=data[first_name]
    at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.2.1.js:2)

Is this due to the version of jquery?

Comment: My bad, I missed the [] around the annoying names you have - I had them when I started and then I removed them for some reason.  Please update your question with just HTML and JS in a [mcve]

Comment: The reason I was using the naming scheme data[first_name] etc. was to differentiate each row.  I am going to modify your code and the naming scheme to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I ultimately removed the brackets and the code is working!  Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Found one other issue:
As Is
ath_data.push({firstName:name,lastName:lastName,classRank:classRank,userID:userID});

To Be
ath_data.push({firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,classRank:classRank,userID:userID});

Comment: Sure. I called it name first and then changed my mind